# Sublime Text 2's phpfmt plugin is not available anymore?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I was used to the [phpfmt plugin for Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/phpfmt), and I'm not able to install it on a fresh installation : the package controller does not seem to find it anymore.

While waiting for a fix, I tried to copy/paste phpfmt folder from Sublime Text's packages folder to my new laptop, but it doesn't seem to work : on the first launch, the plugin is recognized but its directory is deleted.

How can I manually install this plugin ?

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest you upgrade to Sublime Text 3 if at all possible - either the current [public build](https://sublimetext.com/3), or the [dev build](https://sublimetext.com/3dev), which contains a little more bleeding-edge stuff, and requires a license. All development work is now focused on ST3 - [*`"I don't know of any good reason to not use Sublime Text 3"`*](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4) - Will Bond, ST core developer. Additionally, ST2 is [no longer the default download](https://sublimetext.com).

Comment: There are a ton of new features and bugfixes in ST3 that will never be backported. Many of the language syntaxes for code highlighting have been tweaked, updated, rewritten, and/or modernized. A lot is new under the hood as far as the API is concerned, allowing for much cooler plugins that can do things like generate context-dependent popups just by tracking the mouse, give inline documentation assistance, and much more. Read through the changelog on the dev build page I linked above for all the new features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the Package Control page you linked, the package only supports Sublime Text 3. There's a post on [Y Combinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11896851) explaining the original author has deleted his version of the package. There is a guide on [how to downgrade](https://github.com/nanch/sublime-phpfmt) the package, but I'm not sure that includes Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see on the page any information about support being abandoned for Sublime Text 2 (The header still states "phpfmt support for Sublime Text 2/3").

Comment: @MarcBrillault In the upper left-hand corner, where it says `phpfmt` in large letters, there is a logo saying `ST3` right under it. If it worked on both, it would say `ST2/ST3`.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks !

Comment: Note the ST3 badge on the Package Control page. Supported Sublime Text versions are specified in the Package Control [meta data](https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/blob/master/repository/p.json#L1044), maybe the author forgot to update the README.

Comment: MattDMo was faster :)

Comment: Aaand - submitted.

Comment: Thanks, I installed Sublime Text 3 and all works perfectly.
I don't know why I hadn't dont it yet, I thought maybe my licence for ST2 won't work, but it did.